# How to define an array without defining its elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I want to optimize a problem in Python using `scipy`.

To achieve this goal:

1. I define an array of a certain length, but without defining its elements explicitly.
2. Then, I need to use this array to optimize the problem.
3. In the last step, I want to print this array as a result.

Here is the simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

b0 = [1,3,4,2,5]
a = [] # This is the array I want to define. The length of the a should be equal to the b.

def objective(b):
    print(a*b)
    z=a.b.(-1)
    return z 

def constraint(b)
    return b[0]*b[1]*b[2]*b[3]*b[4]

print(objective(b0))
```

Comment: What’s an empty list of length > 0? Python doesn’t really have a concept of “empty element”, except maybe `None`. So, you could say `a = [None] * len(b0)` but I would say that this isn’t generally very useful. I also don’t understand your `a.b.(-1)` syntax. This doesn’t work.

Comment: Are you working with a `numpy` array or a just a regular Python list? Those are two different data structures

Comment: Can you describe how you want to use the array in the optimization problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python has following syntax:

```
array_name = [some_value]*length
```

it creates an array filled with some_value with provided length

so try:

```
a = [None]*len(b)
```

or if you want to not change the type:

```
a=[0]*len(b)
```

as an alternative use numPy array

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in the following manner:

```
import numpy as np

b0 = np.array([1,3,4,2,5])
a = np.array([0]*b0.shape[0])
a.shape
```

**Output**

```
(5,)
```

Cheers